# UWP: any chance to run a background Task like UpdateTask but immediately after Deployment (i.e. install from Store)

Tags: deployment, uwp, background-task

I understand how to use a "windows.updateTask", or "windows.preInstalledConfigTask". The preInstalledConfigTask only works if the app is "pre-Installed", i.e. put inside the Windows Image.

What if I want to run some tasks immediately after the App is deployed, i.e. installed from Store by the User? If that's not possible, how would you achieve the goal with other approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this feature does not exist today.

Feel free to upvote and add comments on UserVoice here:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/20424571-task-for-registering-background-tasks-without-the